# Laravel 5.0 Blade - Require Once

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Is there any way to `require_once 'page.blade.php'` AND have blade compile that page?

I have `require(d)_once` a `page.blade.php` but `{{php code}}` parts would not compiled and are outputted in plain text.

In other words a`@requireOnce-equivalent`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had an epiphany:

`<?php require_once "file.blade.php" ?>` in the master file and replace `{{ \URL::asset() }}` and other blade codes with the simple `<?php echo \URL::asset() ?>`.

Hopefully this will help someone else.